# Joomla, Save Date from custom input fields from the edit.php without a form xml file

Tags: php, joomla, save

I am relatively new in joomla and at the moment I code a component where you can rate and comment an item.
For commenting I only need one file, the edit one and his controller, this should have only a custom input fields without using an XML form file and no plural file with his Default view. 
The problem is I haven´t find out how to save my data to the database by using a jomla save button. When I save my data I am redirected to a new site and the data didn't send via post. I just can use the save() function in my Controller file to Display a message but I can´t Display any post Inputs.

Here is my code as well. I think, something is missing.

My Controller file comments.php

```
class EasyratingControllerComments extends JControllerAdmin
 {
    public function getModel($name = 'Comments', $prefix = 'EasyratingModel', $config = array('ignore_request' => true))
    {
        $model = parent::getModel($name, $prefix, $config);
        return $model;
    }
}
```

my modelfile comments.php

```
class EasyratingModelComments extends JModelList
{
    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        if (empty($config['filter_fields']))
        {
            $config['filter_fields'] = array(
                'id', 'a.id',
                'rating_id', 'a.rating_id',
                'comments', 'a.comments',
            );
        }
            parent::__construct($config);
    }

    protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null)
    {
        $id = JRequest::getInt('id');
        $this->setState('id', $id);
    }

    public function getTable($type = 'Easyrating_comments', $prefix = 'EasyratingTable', $config = array())
    {
        return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
    }

    protected function getListQuery()
    {
        $db = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select(
        $this->getState(
                'list.select',
                'a.id,'a.rating_id, a.comments, a.created_by' 
        )
        );

            $query->from($db->quoteName('#__easyrating_comments').' AS a');
            $query->where('(a.state IN (0, 1))');

        if ($id = $this->getState('id'))
        {
            $query->where('a.rating_id = '.(int) $id);
        }

            return $query;
    }
}
```

my file view.html.php

```
class EasyratingViewComments extends JViewLegacy
{
protected $items;
protected $state;
protected $pagination;

public function display($tpl = null)
{
            $this->items        = $this->get('Items');
            $this->state        = $this->get('State');
            $this->pagination   = $this->get('Pagination');
            $app = JFactory::getApplication();
            $params = $app->getParams();
            $this->assignRef('params', $params);
    parent::display($tpl);
}
```

my file edit.php (not the whole only the important part)

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_easyrating&view=comments&layout=edit&id='.(int) $ratingID); ?>"method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm" class="col col-md-12 rating-comments-main-input-field text-center form-validate comments">
                        <fieldset>
        <textarea name="jform[comments]" id="jform_comments" class="rating-comments-main-textarea" cols="50" rows="30"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right: 15px;" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('comments.save')">                       <i class="icon-new"></i> <?php echo JText::_('JSAVE')?>                             </button>
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
        <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endPane'); ?>
                        </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please minimize your code so that there is a short listing that shows your problem?

Comment: Hi DIDoS.
I didn´t know where the Problem is so I posted most of the code.

Comment: This is considered a code dump and should not be done on StackOverflow. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for instructions.

Comment: Hello DIDoS. Thanks for explaining. I edit my post and reduced the code. Hope that is now ok for you. More reduce will be too much so no one knows what I want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submitting the form the controller function comments.save is called. I guess as you have no save() - function in your controller, this is handled by the default method, which uses the form xml file to validate (which you dont have). To override I think your controller should be in a file named com_easyrating/controllers/comments.php

```
class EasyRatingControllerComments{
  function save(){ 
    // here you should be able to handle your input
  }
}
```

I think to make use of the built in joomla functionality, you need to have an xml-file defined. I did not understand why you don't? Using this is the standard Joomla way to handle form input. Check some docs at [docs.joomla.org/...](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Example_of_a_frontend_update_function)

An easy way to get a component framework is to use a component creator initially, f.ex. [component-creator.com](https://www.component-creator.com/en/)

Comment: Hello jonasfh,thanks for the hint. I am using the standard joomla way in my component but for this I need a special way without an xml file, because I am also using jquery to rig the textarea field. I also didn´t need the list file. I already tried to use the save function in my controller but I got an 500 error when I try to usw the post value I got from the textarea. With your hint I started a new try and now I got the post data. I think I am on the right way. Last step is to store the data in my database. I think I will manage it. Thank you very much for helping me.